# Emulator stops at the boot interface when running Helloworld program

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I try to run a helloworld example on the Android Studio.The example is generated antomatically by the studio，but it stop at the boot interface.

I've got the following errors:

```
04-04 06:36:32.941 939-939/? E/lowmemorykiller: Kernel does not support
memory pressure events or in-kernel low memory killer
04-04 06:36:33.114 941-941/? E/libEGL:load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
04-04 06:36:33.235 941-941/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
04-04 06:36:33.778 941-962/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-04 06:36:35.217 1008-1010/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you have set very low configuration for your emulator

Answer (score 2):

You have to check your configuration. It seems configuration issue in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you configuration is not right then sometimes it gives errors so make sure configuration is correct if again it shows error you need to create a new emulator.